# Storing one or several sql statements as a variable in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a stored procedure. Is it possible to store multiple sql statements in a variable inside a stored procedure and later execute it when the procedure is invoked?

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure
(
@parameter1 int = QUERIES_HERE
)
AS
/*something like execute @parameter1*/
RETURN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(500)

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = 123'

EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```